# In Nest.js, how to serve static content file/s bundled together with my JSON object in my API Response

Tags: typescript, express, api-design

In my Nest.js API I have a GET that must return a db row, *together* with (up to) 6 image files (base64 encoded), in the Response.

What I *can* do is this:

6 of the columns in the db contain the unique files names (the actual images are in a folder called "image-uploads"), and together with the path I can use the @Res decorator to send any *one* of them back e.g.

```
@Get('/findVehicleEntry/:id')
async findVehicleEntry(@Param('id') id: number, @Res() res) {
    const resVehicle: Vehicle = await this.vehiclesService.findVehicleEntry(id);
    if (resVehicle) {
        res.sendFile(resVehicle.photo1, { root: 'image-uploads' });
    }
}
```

The above successfully downloads one image file as Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"

My plan is (and what I don't know how to do is):

Firstly, get the image from the folder and *into a variable*, then run a base64 encode on it, then set resVehicle.photo1 equal to that base64 string, and do the same for the other 5 images, then do a res.send(resVehicle);

Something like this:

```
@Get('/findVehicleEntry/:id')
    async findVehicleEntry(@Param('id') id: number, @Res() res) {
    const resVehicle: Vehicle = await this.vehiclesService.findVehicleEntry(id);
    if (resVehicle) {
        let image = something.get('resVehicle.photo1', 'my/path/to/image-uploads');
        image = Buffer.from(image).toString('base64');
        resVehicle.photo1 = image;
        // do the same for the other 5 images
        res.send(resVehicle);
    }
}
```

This is the first time I've used Nest/Express/Node, actually this is the first API I have written so my idea/design may be totally off. Any suggestions welcome. Many thanks.

Edit: Been reading that base64 encoding of large files is not a good idea. I'm happy to drop the base64 idea, main question is how to get my db row JSON object and the 6 images into the same Response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that base64 encoding of the images is not a good idea.

The traditional solution here is:
You **don't push the images**, you provide the image path in your json response and let the API consumer use the path to get the image.

- keep the actual image files in a publicly available folder, not in a database. This means it should be accessible from the browser at for example `yourdomain.com/images/image232.jpg`
- in your database, store the path to those images as a string (`image1: "yourdomain.com/images/image232.jpg"`)
- serve your json response containing the path (`{make:"Toyota", image1:"yourdomain.com/images/image232.jpg"}`)
- Whoever is consuming your API can then use the path to get the image.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ja, that's (almost) exactly what I did. I send back the file names in the JSON, and have exposed another endpoint that can be used to get an image file. The added benefit is that the frontend gets all the data first, and  builds the page while the image calls happen in the background. It's working well. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Ps. Tried to upvote your answer, but I can't, not enough reps.

Comment: If you think this is the right answer to your question, instead of upvoting, you can actually mark it as the answer.